# Why is my FPGA clock so slow

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, hdl

To preface this I am a complete beginner with verilog and FPGAs in general. But I recently purchased a MAX1000 board to start learning things on and one of the first programs that I made was this:

```
module top (
    input CLK12M,
    output TEST
);
    
    assign TEST = CLK12M;
    endmodule
```

I then configured the pins so that I could look at TEST on my oscilliscope. I expected to see a 12MHz clock as that is what the device has and how it is configured but instead I am seeing a ~320Hz clock signal. For reference this is what the .sdc file looks like.

```
create_clock -name  CLK12M -period 83.333 [get_ports {CLK12M}]
derive_clock_uncertainty
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to see the 12Mhz clock signal?

Comment: Can you actually read a clock signal straight out to a regular pin like that? I've never tried it but I suspect you can't because the reason clocks have special pins is because they go to a dedicated fan-out distribution network so the clock is delivered to all parts of the FPGA with minimal skew. Instead, try making a counter that counts clock cycles and toggles a pin every n clock cycles and measure that, because your second line of code is just a timing constraint. It doesn't actually set the clock since that is determined by hardware or the PLL.

Comment: Look up clock forwarding in Intel FPGA's.  Here's a link https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Quartus-Prime-Software/Recommended-procedure-for-FPGA-clock-forwarding/td-p/655941.  They say ALTCLKCTL is the best approach.  Basically you want to run your input clock into the FPGA and into a DDR register in the I/O block.  You clock out a 1 on the rising edge and a 0 on the falling edge.

Comment: You typically can't even read a clock signal like a regular signal. You need to rely on special keywords like rising_edge() in VHDL and whatever equivalent it is in Verilog to access it.

Comment: Also have a look at Figure 16 of this https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/ug_m10_gpio.pdf.  It shows a DDIO_OUT block.  `Outclock` is your clock.  `O_DATAOUT0` you tie to a '0' or low.  `O_DATAOUT1` you tie to a '1' or high.  You can instantiate a DDIO_OUT block in your HDL and code up the signals accordingly.  Have a look in this document for reference https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_altddio.pdf

Comment: Here is the VHDL block to instantiate http://www.pldworld.com/_altera/html/_sw/q2help/source/mega/mega_file_altddio_output.htm.  I am assuming this is the same or similar for a MAX10 device.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help I didn't realize the clock was treated so specially. It looks like it was just the fact that the clock cant be passed through so easily. When I used an always block to trigger a signal on the rising edge of the clock I got a 6MHz output which makes sense.

Comment: @DKNguyen, there's nothing magical about clocks going out on I/O pins. You can route them out to FPGA ordinary I/O pins, as I've done on many designs.

Comment: @DKNguyen, Verilog makes no special distinction between clocks and other signals. As far as the language is concerned, you can use a clock signal as an input to combinatorial logic, and you can make a register respond to the rising or falling edge of any arbitrary signal (not only clocks). What is synthesizable, of course, is a different question.

Comment: @TonyM What is the cause of the OP's situtation then?

Comment: @DKNguyen, dunno, I'm not trying to answer the OP's question of why they can't do it, am vastly too busy at work unfortunately. I'm correcting your comments saying it can't be done. As quick evidence, I added a clock output pin to a MAX 10 design I have, synthesized it and used the RTL viewer to show the PLL output driving the output pin directly. It's not an uncommon thing to do.